# Swift - Why is my function within a function not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am working on a project for a simple quiz app.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
    var pickedAnswer: Bool = false
    var questionNumber: Int = 0

    //Place your instance variables here


    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstQuestion = allQuestions.list[0]
        questionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText

    }

    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            pickedAnswer = true
        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            pickedAnswer = false
        }

        checkAnswer()

        questionNumber = questionNumber + 1

        nextQuestion()

    }


    func updateUI() {

    }


    func nextQuestion() {

        if questionNumber <= 12 {
            questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionText
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Quiz Complete", message: "You have completed the quiz, do you want to start over?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.startOver()
            })

            alert.addAction(restartAction)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }


    func checkAnswer() {

        let correctAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer

        if correctAnswer == pickedAnswer {
            print("You got it!")
        } else {
            print("Wrong!")
        }

    }


    func startOver() {

        questionNumber = 0
        nextQuestion()

    }



}
```

The user can answer true or false to a set of questions. The questions are stored in an array, 0 - 12, on a separate file. There is a variable to determine the question number.

```
   var questionNumber: Int = 0
```

There is an if/else statement within a function run after every question - if the question number variable <= 12, the next question is asked and the question number variable is increased by 1.

```
 @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            pickedAnswer = true
        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            pickedAnswer = false
        }


    checkAnswer()

    questionNumber = questionNumber + 1

    nextQuestion()

}


func updateUI() {

}


func nextQuestion() {

    if questionNumber <= 12 {
        questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionText
    }
    else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Quiz Complete", message: "You have completed the quiz, do you want to start over?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.startOver()
        })

        alert.addAction(restartAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Otherwise, they are asked if they want to restart.

The goal is that when the user reaches question #12, they are presented with a UIAlertView that congratulates them and offers a chance to restart with the "Restart" button.

The "Restart" button runs a function which sets the question number variable back to 0 and should begin the function with an if/else statement which asks the first question. (Changes the UI text)

```
 func startOver() {


    questionNumber = 0
    nextQuestion()

}
```

However, on pressing "Restart" the UI text does not change from the final question to the first question and the only way to initiate a change is to press on the "true" or "false" button.

This runs a different function and skips the first question to the 2nd.

From the fact that the "true" or "false" button didn't initiate the restart alert (the question count not being above 12), I can assume that the function ran correctly and set my variable to 0.

However, function restarting the app did not run when pressing "Restart".

**What error is causing this? What can I change to make my function run on pressing "Restart"?**

**Tl;dr: Pressing the Restart button runs a function which successfully sets a new variable, but doesn't run the additional function specified. The only way to proceed is to press one of the app's "true" or "false" buttons, messing up the flow of the app.**

Thanks so much for the help - Still new to Swift and eager to learn!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Try a clean build and if that does not help, put a breakpoint to the reset function and look what's going on there using the debugger.

Comment: Is your `startOver` function actually run when the Restart button is pressed?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, the startOver function is run because questionNumber = 0 is successfully assigned. However, the nextQuestion function is not run - it would either return the correct result or it would give a popup dialog, but neither is the case. The user is forced to press "True" or "False" and at that point it jumps forward 2 questions, but you can see that questionNumber = 0 was successfully assigned

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through the code. Ensure the correct code is being called. Ensure all variables have expected values.

Comment: @rmaddy I used the debugger and followed all of the variables. I also restarted Xcode and cleaned the project a few times. All of the variables have the expected values and the correct code is being called. I ran a simulator and after pressing "Restart" nothing happened, but after tapping anywhere on the screen (not the true/false buttons) it worked properly. Is there something I can fix to make it work without having to tap on the screen? Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: @rmaddy I actually just got it to change successfully, but there was a 10 - 15 second delay. Is this normal? Is there a command to force a UI refresh without this delay, or is the delay an abnormal issue?

Comment: My suggestion for you, would be to reduce the number of questions to only 1 and make sure that you get the restart process working - just keep showing the same question and then the restart alert. Once you’re sure that works then add the rest of the questions. As for the ‘UI refreshing’ problem, it’s impossible to say with what you have given here but you shouldn’t need to do any explicit ‘refreshing’ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the button is named restart. There are other functions in swift that are also `restart()`. Just change it and it should work.